# javascript for loop random return

Tags: javascript, random, for-loop, while-loop

I have this small source of code

```
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
     console.log(i);
     (function (i) {
         if (elements[i]["id"] == id) {
             index = i;
             console.log(i);
         }
     })(i);
}

console.log(index);
```

I want to find an array's element index where sub element "id" = id; but it returns sometimes 0 simetimes 1. This code is inside a function that is inside a class. and I call the same function twice but with different parameters outside of the class, so first it must show 0 and than 1, but sometimes it shows 1 and than 0. so can you help me? I tried this method too but it doesn't work.

```
var i = 0;
while (i < elements.length) {
    console.log(elements[i]["id"]);
    if (elements[i]["id"] == id) {
        index = i;
        break;
    } else if (elements[i]["id"] != id) {
        i++;
    }
}

console.log(index);
```

[**Here is my test page**](http://www.myserver.net63.net/), If you open it with Chrome (sometimes it happens but in Firefox it happens mostly) you will see that sometimes small image appears but sometimes it disapears when you press the button. You can also see the console output in "inspect elements -> console"

**EDIT**

I changed my code for better debug like this (as Lando suggested) :

```
for (i in elements){
    console.log("comparing elements['"+ i +"']['id']: "+ elements[i]["id"] +" with id:' "+ id + "'");
        if(elements[i]["id"] == id){
            index = i;
        }
    }

console.log(index);
```

and got  console ouput:

```
comparing elements['0']['id']: id2 with id:' id1' Slideshow.js:140
comparing elements['1']['id']: id1 with id:' id1' Slideshow.js:140
1 Slideshow.js:147
comparing elements['0']['id']: id2 with id:' id2' Slideshow.js:140
comparing elements['1']['id']: id1 with id:' id2' Slideshow.js:140
0
```

When it should be:

```
comparing elements['0']['id']: id1 with id:' id1' Slideshow.js:140
comparing elements['1']['id']: id2 with id:' id1' Slideshow.js:140
0 Slideshow.js:147
comparing elements['0']['id']: id1 with id:' id2' Slideshow.js:140
comparing elements['1']['id']: id2 with id:' id2' Slideshow.js:140
1
```

**EDIT 2**

After seeing the output it turns out that objects in array "elements" change places, `elements[0]["id"]` becames `"id2"` where it should be `"id1"` I can't still difinetly say why is this happening or what to do to fix it. so please if you have any ideas share it.

[Here is my JSfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/PxfM8/)

Comment: else if (elements[i]["id"] != id) ?? you can replace this with else

Comment: That was'nt an answer but a comment :)

Comment: sidenote: the closure in you first snippet is unneeded. You only need this type of construct if something *async* is involved (e.g. binding event handlers, timeouts, ...)

Comment: I updated my post where you can see a test web page and the problem itself

Comment: Your code is working as expected, reason you are seeing it return 0 and 1 is because that method is being called twice, once with "id1" and once with "id2"  $("#has").click(function(){
                slideshow.animate('#id1', {opacity: 1}, 500);
                slideshow.animate('#id2', {x:200, y:100, opacity: 1}, 300);
            });

Comment: so it means that i could not be able to animate 2 objects same time? I really don't know what to change to make multiple animations to work same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was the problem. It seemed that sometimes small image was loaded the first so large image was appearing at the top. It is all about image loading. Thank you anyway for your answers, everyone helped me to debug the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must change your code to this, with no inner function (closure) (the first console.log will help you debug your code (or you could just use firebug and set a breakpoint in that line)

```
for (i in elements){
    console.log("comparing elements['"+ i +"']['id']: "+ elements[i]["id"] +" with id:'"+ id + "'");
    if(elements[i]["id"] == id){
        index = i;
        console.log(i);
    }
}

console.log(index);
```

remember that javascript arrays are not necessarily zero based, and not even necessarily sequential, so the "for in" will help you avoid possible errors. I removed the closure because I don't see you actually need it in this case.

Comment: I did what you wrote to do and modified my first post.

Comment: Well as you can see from the logs the problem is not actually the for loop, but the array: in both runs the arrays is like this ['id2', 'id1'] so in the first run when you search for 'id1' it will return '1' while in the second run when you search for 'id2' it will return '0'.